# Escape special characters while sending email through AWS ses

Tags: amazon-web-services, go, amazon-ses

Hello I am using AWS SES SDK V2 to send emails. I have a case where sender name is like `Michael čisto`. If I pass this name directly to AWS email input struct then it gives me following error:

`operation error SESv2: SendEmail, https response error StatusCode: 400, BadRequestException: Missing '"'`

Here is my code:

```
package main

import (
    "context"

    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go-v2/aws"
    awsconfig "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go-v2/config"
    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go-v2/service/sesv2"
    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go-v2/service/sesv2/types"
)

func main() {
    name := "Michael čisto"
    body := "test email body"
    subject := "test email"
    CharSet := "UTF-8"
    /* Assemble the email */
    input := &sesv2.SendEmailInput{
        Destination: &types.Destination{
            CcAddresses: []string{},
            ToAddresses: []string{receiverEmail},
        },
        Content: &types.EmailContent{
            Simple: &types.Message{
                Body: &types.Body{
                    Html: &types.Content{
                        Charset: aws.String(CharSet),
                        Data:    aws.String(body),
                    },
                },
                Subject: &types.Content{
                    Charset: aws.String(CharSet),
                    Data:    aws.String(subject),
                },
            },
        },
        ReplyToAddresses: []string{"\"" + name + "\" <" + senderEmail + ">"},
        FromEmailAddress: aws.String("\"" + name + "\" <" + senderEmail + ">"),
    }
    cfg, err := awsconfig.LoadDefaultConfig(context.TODO(),
        awsconfig.WithRegion("us-east-1"),
    )
    client := sesv2.NewFromConfig(cfg)
    emailResp, err = client.SendEmail(context.TODO(), input)
}
```

Can anyone help me to figure out how to escape these kind of characters in GO ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to format the address using [mail.Address.String](https://pkg.go.dev/net/mail#Address.String):

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "net/mail"
)

func main() {
    a := mail.Address{Name: "Michael čisto", Address: "sender@example.com"}
    fmt.Println(a.String())
    // Output:
    // =?utf-8?q?Michael_=C4=8Disto?= <sender@example.com>
}
```

---

**In case your domain contains non-ASCII characters**:

Please note that Amazon SES does not support the SMTPUTF8 extension. If the domain part of an address (the part after the @ sign) contains non-ASCII characters, they must be encoded using Punycode (see [types.BulkEmailEntry](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go-v2/service/sesv2@v1.15.1/types#BulkEmailEntry)). `mail.Address.String` does not do this for you. But you can use [idna.ToASCII](https://pkg.go.dev/golang.org/x/net@v0.2.0/idna#ToASCII) to convert the domain yourself.